# How to curve edges of UIImageview in swift ios?

Tags: swift

I used

```
let view = UIImageView(CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
view.cornerRadius = 10
self.mainView.addSubview(view)
```

This rounds the corner I want round the edges

Comment: I think you can use UIBezierPath to draw that kind of complicated UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard technique is to

1. Define a `UIBezierPath` for the shape.
2. Make a `CAShapeLayer` using that path.
3. Define the image view’s layer’s mask to use that shape layer.

E.g.

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedCornerView: UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 17 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 75 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        
        var point = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius)
        path.move(to: point)
        
        var controlPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x + cornerRadius, y: rect.minY)
        point = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        
        point = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerRadius, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius)
        controlPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x - cornerRadius, y: rect.minY)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        
        controlPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: point.y + cornerRadius)
        point = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        
        point = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY - cornerRadius)
        controlPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: point.y - cornerRadius)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        
        controlPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x - cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY)
        point = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        
        point = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY - cornerRadius)
        controlPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x + cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        
        controlPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: point.y - cornerRadius)
        point = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        
        point = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius)
        controlPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: point.y + cornerRadius)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: point, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        
        path.close()
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.mask = shapeLayer
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Yields:

[image]

You’ll have to play around with values for `cornerRadius` and `lineWidth` for your image view’s dimensions, but hopefully this illustrates the idea. The default values I used in the code above was for a 300×300 image view.

Note, I implemented the path in `layoutSubviews` so that it would respond to resizing of your image view. I also make it `@IBDesignable` so that you could see it rendered in IB if you happened to be using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap image inside UIView

```
let image = UIImageView(CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100))
let view = UIView(CGRect(x:0,y:10,width:100,height:100))
view.cornerRadius = 10
view.addSubiew(image)
self.mainView.addSubview(view)
```

**Swift 4**

```
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100))
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:10,width:100,height:100))
view.layer.cornerRadius = 30
view.addSubview(image)
self.mainView.addSubview(view)
```